# Not able to print in color on terminal

Tags: python, python-3.x, colors, terminal, console

As given in an answer on [Print in terminal with colors using Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/print-in-terminal-with-colors-using-python) , I am trying to print in color on console/terminal using following code:

```
RED = "\e[31m"
NORMAL = "\e[0m"

print("TESTING")
print(RED+"TESTING"+NORMAL)
print("TESTING")
```

However, it is not working and only giving following output:

```
TESTING
\e[31mTESTING\e[0m      # IN BLACK, THOUGH IT IS SHOWING COLOR HERE.
TESTING
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved? I am using Python version 3.5.3 on Debian Stable Linux.

Comment: `\e` is not the correct escape sequence to enable colours. Did you read the answers properly?

Comment: I am referring to answer by @IgorSarcevic and using above code from a script.

Comment: That *single answer* that used `\e` is wrong. `\e` is an escape sequence in a different shell, not in Python. I've left a comment on it stating how it is wrong; the answer doesn't even work in bash.

Comment: Your question links to the whole question, not to a specific answer, I had to search for it (it only appears on page 2 when sorting by votes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have found a wrong answer; `\e` is not a valid escape sequence in Python. In some `echo` implementations, `\e` is an escape sequence for the [ASCII ESC character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character#ASCII_escape_character), but in Python you need to use a different notation.

The rest of the answers on that page use correct forms, either `\x1b` or `\033`.